# how to add customListView items to the EndlessAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view, cwac-endless

How to add `customListView` items to the `EndlessAdapter` through the `add` method? Once a new instance of the `CustomListViewAdapter` is instanciated with the constructor of the `EndlessAdapter` i need to add elements to my list otherwise it will just recycle old elements.

Comment: can you see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
@Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {          
        if ( scroll&&list.getLastVisiblePosition() == list.getAdapter().getCount() - 1
                && list.getChildAt(list.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= list.getHeight()) {
                //add your new elements
            }
}
```

you can add your new items in your last element of your listview, you can load your listview 10 and when a user comes to last element of list it load 10 items again

Comment: im  using this library though https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/tree/master